# Saving data to buffer when internet is not available

Tags: android, gps

Iam begginer in developing like 3 month and looking for help.

Iam developing app when GPS possition is send to server through JSON.

Iam looking for function if internet is not available GPS data will be stored to some kind of

buffer and when is internet available it will send all what was stored.

I dont know where to start can you help me pls? or if its even possible

Thank you !

Comment: There is no ready to use "function" to do that. You will have to write your own system that checks if the internet connection is available and queue your requests

Answer (score 1):

There are quite several options... the best would be to start reading : ["Android Storage Options"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Easiest & quickest way would be `SharedPreferences`... the recomended way would be probably to store the GPS positions in `SQLiteDatabase` and send them when connection is available.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the comment you have received there are a number of ways to achieve this but they all involve a LOT of coding.

Firstly store the data in an appropriate storage format, Probably best to use SQLite database with a content provider

Secondly you should be using an intent service possibly in conjunction with an account manager depending on your requirements

lastly, the most important bit that answers your question is to use the Android Sync Adapter.
The SyncAdapter will determine when the best time is to send data

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Comment: +1 for your answer. but I don't think that all the way "involve a LOT of coding"... for more simple use cases.. there can be simple solutions that don't involve that much code :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest `SharedPreferences`

```
final String MY_GPS = "GPS_STRING";
SharedPreferences  pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
/*
 *Method to store data
 */
void storeGPS(String myjson){

        Editor editor = pref.edit();

        editor.putString(MY_GPS , myjson);
        editor.commit();
}
/*
 *Method to retreive data
 */
String getGPS(){
return pref.getString(MY_GPS);
}
```